# How to add flutter address to node.js CORS?

Tags: node.js, flutter, cors

I have a React application and a flutter application where both are supposed to communicate to the node.js backend. So in order to make them work, I needed to add CORS to the server. The current configuration of CORS is as follows:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
}))
```

Here I know the address of React that it runs on localhost and on port 3000 so I added it and it is working fine but how do I add the CORS for the flutter android app. I don't know it's address, so how should I add the origin in the server?

Comment: A Flutter app isn't a browser; it doesn't have an origin, it won't enforce CORS.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/236968/can-we-use-cors-policy-to-restrict-api-calls-from-native-mobile-app

Answer (score -1):

Flutter web is like any other client side web application. All rules that apply to React are equally valid for Flutter web.

Comment: It's for android